# How to implement a generic slice appender?

Tags: go, reflection, slice

I'm relatively new to `go`.  I'm trying to write a generic "appender" function.  This is a simplification, but its an attempt to create a clean interface for processing some lists.  Specifically, I have questions about the two errors that this generates:

```
package main

type GenericFunc func() *interface{}
func Append(ints interface{}, f GenericFunc) {
    ints = append(ints, f())
}

func ReturnInt() *int {
    i := 1
    return &i
}

func main() {
    var ints []*int
    Append(ints, ReturnInt)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SmeKgEq3Y0y)

> prog.go:5:18: first argument to append must be slice; have interface
>   {} prog.go:15:11: cannot use ReturnInt (type func() *int) as type
>   GenericFunc in argument to Append

1. Why can't `ReturnInt` be of type `GenericFunc`?  If this doesn't work, I'm not understanding how `interface{}` can be used with functions at all.. can it?
2. How can you accept a "generic" slice and append to it using reflection?  This would involve checking that `GenericFunc` returns the same type that the slice is, but after that appending should be possible.

Comment: Why not just use `append`? It is already generic. For example you can do this [`ints = append(ints, ReturnInt())`](https://play.golang.org/p/pj5sjlINtNF). Also note that, apart from a few builtins, Go does not support generics, and therefore an attempt to implement generic types in your go program is gonna result in either failure or a solution that's lacking.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I'm well aware of the generics situation in go, but there are appropriate times to use it.  In this case, its a single, very isolated, small function that can unlock a lot of other cleanliness and go-like idioms throughout the rest of my application.  Feels like the appropriate level of tradeoff for me.

Comment: Jared just FYI, I'm not the one who gave you the downvote, so I can't answer your question. As to the rest of your comment: fair enough.

Comment: Soon: https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/tEQKEIfLz5K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types `func() *interface{}` (type type of GenericFunc) and `(type func() *int)` (the type of ReturnInt) are different types. One returns a `*interface{}`.  The other returns a `*int`.  The types are not assignable to each other.

Use this function to generically append the result of a function to a slice:

```
func Append(sp interface{}, f interface{}) {
    s := reflect.ValueOf(sp).Elem()
    s.Set(reflect.Append(s, reflect.ValueOf(f).Call(nil)[0]))
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var ints []*int
Append(&ints, ReturnInt)
```

The function will panic if the argument is not a pointer to a slice or the function does not return a value assignable to a slice element.

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/9vbOXvRZ0nk)